# How to respond to email questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, email

Today I received an email referencing one of my answers and asking questions about. The questions go beyond commentary. This undoubtedly falls into the 'if you have a new question, please create a new question on Stack Overflow for it' category.

What language should be used to inform the person that emailing me questions is not acceptable - but also encourage them to open a question on Stack Overflow instead?

Comment: Depending on how you think the other user got your email, you could always just ignore it.  Then the other user (or spammer) might just give up and not pester you further.  If you _really_ want to advise them, then just be frank and tell them pretty much what you told us in this meta post.  But be prepared for a "I'm banned because SO is mean" sob story.

Comment: Apparently you made your email address public - that's your own choice. But now you're dealing with a you-question, not a stackoverflow question. Deal with it how you see fit. I'd not make my email address public myself.

Comment: I tend to answer something like `Hi, unfortunately I'm unable to answer questions through E-Mail. This looks like something you should start a new question about on Stack Overflow. Feel free to send me a link once you're done and I'll take a peek if I have the time." (The latter is optional, of course)

Comment: I didn't make email address obviously public. I have my PGP key posted - which is linked to an email address. I also have a link to my website- which might have a reference to my email as well- I'm in the middle of rewritten it and the new version will not have my email.

Comment: Ha, assumptions always backfire :) However this person got hold of your email it doesn't change the fact that this is a question directed at you, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really is up to you.

I tend to answer something like

> Hi, unfortunately I'm unable to answer questions through E-Mail.
>
> This looks like something you should start a new question about on Stack Overflow.
>
> Feel free to send me a link once you're done and I'll take a peek if I have the time.

<sub>(The latter bit is optional, of course, in cases where the question is really *interesting*.)</sub>

This has worked in most cases, except maybe one or two where the user didn't get the hint and kept on sending messages.

Comment: I still cannot believe people do stuff like that...

Comment: @JonH: you never got an email saying "hey I like your free software but I could not find the source code, plz send it to me asap"?

Comment: @Jongware I receive mails like that on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3):

I always update my answer publicly like this (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35361364/1622493)):

> a sample was sent to my personal mail address. I don't know if this is allowed by StackOverflow, but please note that I don't allow this. I answer questions on StackOverflow on a voluntary basis, but *I do not answer questions for free that are sent to my personal e-mail address.*

Note that I didn't share my e-mail address. The OP just found it online and decided he could mail me directly. He didn't just share a sample, he also asked me further questions. This is the answer sent to this person privately:

> I’ve forwarded your question to our sales representative so that he can prepare an offer for you. Once you’ve approved the offer, our technical team can answer your question.

This makes a clear distinction between what is done on a voluntary basis (post a question on SO, and I'll help you out for free if I have the time), and what isn't available for free (ask me a question personally, and you have to pay me if you want me to spend time on your problem).

In my experience, this is the only way to stop people from mailing you.